# Test login three times with mockito throws an Exception!

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a test but i am not quite good with it, i want to verify that when the methods login is called three times with wrong username and password it throws an exception is this test correct:

```
@Test(expected=Login.TooManyLoginException.class)
public void testLogin_WrongUser_More_Than_Three_Times() {

    System.out.println("Testing login With Wrong User More than three Times Method");       

    Login mock=mock(Login.class);

    when(mock.login(username, password)).thenThrow(new TooManyLoginException("Ha intentado entrar demasiadas veces el programa se cerrara"));

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        mock.login(username, password);

}
```

An example might be nice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact i found a clear explanation here

http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/Mockito.LoginServiceExample

Now i do understand Mock objects.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [The Mockito documentation on multiple executions](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4). It describes how you can get the mock to do a throw on the third request. Which is what I think you are after.